# Symfony 2.8 php app/console cache:clear not working

Tags: symfony, caching

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Compile Error: appDevDebugProjectContainer::getDoctrine_Orm_LogsEntityManagerService(): Failed opening required '/home/training/Projects/MyLine/app/cache/dev/jms_diextra/doctrine/EntityManager_59ad554
>     d29d1c.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')

- When I try to clear my cache with  `php app/console cache:clear` in symfony 2.8, the above error comes up.
- What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Did you try to remove the cache folder with command line `rm -R` ?

Comment: Yep. Same issue. After i remove the cache and creates a new one, if i give the command, the same issue comes up :(.

Comment: Have you followed up this instructions?? https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup/file_permissions.html

Comment: I followed the instructions at your suggestion, but it still gives the same error. It clears my cache it seems, but it still gives the same error. I will try to update the jms_diextra bundle and I hope it will work.

Comment: Updating the bundle didn't work.